# QT logging with text formatting

Tags: c++, qt

According [manual](https://evileg.com/en/post/154/) in order to log into file I need to open it in `main`:

```
QScopedPointer<QFile>   m_logFile;

void messageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    m_logFile.reset(new QFile("logFile.txt"));

    m_logFile.data()->open(QFile::Append | QFile::Text);
    qInstallMessageHandler(messageHandler);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Then I can log to it:

```
qDebug(logDebug()) << "Hello Debug";
```

But how to organize logging in more convenient way with text formatting like `printf`:

```
printf("Hello Debug %d, my_int);
```

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to stream-like API you can simply use [`qDebug`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qDebug) like `printf`.

```
qDebug("Hello Debug %d", my_int);
```

Similar with logging [category](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html#qCDebug-1):

```
qCDebug(category, "Hello Debug %d", my_int);
```

---

> **Tip**
>
> The following message format produces nice links to the lines printed the trace in the *QtCreator*'s *Application Output* pane.
>
> ```
> QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN=[%{time process}] %{threadid} file:/%{file}:%{line}: %{message} %{if-critical}%{backtrace}%{endif}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write the integer object.

```
qDebug(logDebug()) << "Hello Debug "<< my_int;
```

or

```
qDebug(logDebug()) << "Hello Debug"<< " "<<my_int;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`QString::asprintf()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#asprintf) or, preferably [`QString::arg()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg) to produce `QString` using `printf`-like format syntax and then use it with `qDebug()`.